# How to solve External Redirect attack-- from a Security Scan on the site

Tags: php, security, redirect, header

So the Security Scan complained about External Redirect.

I think it was bc this line in the code: 
  `header('location:'.$_POST['some_input']);`
it was meant for some internal page jump, but could be abused by external url.
I have wrapped that in to a redirect function,
basically it will add our url base to it

```
define('BASE_URL','https://example.com/');
function redirect($url)
{
    header('location:'.BASE_URL.$url)
}
```

Then the above code become `$this->redirect($_POST['some_input'])`

I thought in this way, even an attacker make $_POST['some_input'] = 'attackersite.com', it would just redirect to a bad url.

But then when i did the scan again it is exact same External Redirect complains. 
Is it still not safe or the scanning software just doesn't care as long as they think you are doing the redirect?  If that is the only way to solve it is create a mapping of redirect URL?

[OWASP ZAP REPORT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg0dt.png)

Comment: It is probably not a good idea to do a redirect to URL that you are getting via POST. You might want to change your business logic if possible. Additionally, you could at least sanitize the POST input and also change your function to do a conditional redirect (redirect only if the domain name is yours or something like that).

Comment: Rather than the redirect URL getting generated entirely from the POST input, you could generate part of the URL based on the POST value. Something like `$yoursite?val='.$_POST['some_input'].'`

Comment: What security scan software is it? Please provide the relevant output from the report. For all I know it could be referring to XSS and not PHP.

Comment: It was OWASP zap.  I have added the report screen shot in. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I changed to a url mapping, covert post data to url instead of directly use the post data.  it solved the problem. I think OWASP does not care what URL is. as long as it looks like you directly redirect from a post it consider unsafe.